# Bootstrap carousel: first slide more long than the others

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I develop a progress bar for the bootstrap carousel. You can see it here:
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/xaRam

**The problem:**

For a reason I do not understand, the duration of the first slide is more long than the others. All the next transitions are OK.

**I used:**

- Bootstrap carousel:
- A modified version of the bootstrao carousel with a timer transition : http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/carousel-with-timer-and-caption

**Solutions I tried to fix the problem:**

- change the carousel interval in the JS (didn't work)
- play with the different value of transition in the CSS, like in the transition timer carousel (didn't work)
- add a data-interval to each slide (didn't work)
- add a setTimeout to the carousel (partially worked)

Do you have an idea to fix this bug?
Thank you!

Comment: Hi Roy.23. What I have done is on the first link of my message: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/xaRam